# url-encoding in browser address bar

Tags: browser, url-encoding, address-bar

When I put some non-alpha-numeric symbols in browser address bar, they got url-encoded. For example, [https://www.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=привет](https://www.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82) turns into https://www.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=%EF%F0%E8%E2%E5%F2.

The question is: what do those two percent-prefixed hex digits mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

they are bytes of the 
Windows 1251 encoding of Cyrillic. Since there are only six of them, they can't be UTF-8, since it takes 12 bytes of UTF-8 for 6 chars of Cyrillic.

The code chart for CP1251 can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251.

Just like 20 is hex for a space, each of the Cyrillic characters has its numeric value, expressible as two hex digits.

Comment: Thank's! The question that I can't figure out: how many bytes stand for F2 for example? How is it counted?

Comment: %F2 represents one byte, the character т in CP1251.

Comment: Is this number -- F2 -- just a (serial) number of character т in CP1251?